# How to get specific row from a database in django/postgresSQL? (modelform)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-forms

so I know of the model.objects.all() but is there a way that i could get all of the items for a certain part of that database? 
say I have a database of books and under that I have the author and illustrator fields that you can enter. what would I enter so that it returned  a list of all the authors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write like

`Books.objects.values('author').distinct()`

You can check for distinct function in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#distinct